# How to add a group by to a page footer with calculations in Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report which has two fields: amount and currency. The currency varies, (i.e USD, GBP etc.) I need to add a footer to each page with the total from each currency. eg :

```
Total in USD : 1200 | Total in GBP : 1890
```

There can be 100s of currencies. And I need to display each currency like the above in the footer of each page. There is no way to pre-determine the currency, therefore need to get the total in the Jasper Report itself.

Comment: could you please provide your dataset example or at least a sort of example of your complete report? maybe a link to a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to add all currencies, use if clause to set currency to 0 where ever the value is null.
Adding details as requested 
For Example create variable 1 
Name: 'USD'
Class: `java.math.BigDecimal`
Calculation: SUM
Variable Expression: `$F{Amount}*ExchangeRate`
Similarly Create variable 2 'GBP'
Now create a variable to display in footer
class: String
Variable Expression:

```java
($V{USD}.equals('0')?null:"Total in USD :"+$V{USD})
+
($V{GBP}.equals('0')?null:"Total in GBP :"+$V{GBP})
```

Comment: can you explain it a bit more?? i need to display all the currencies as i mentioned above.

Comment: Added details in answer as you requested.